# SOQL lookup query between standard and custom object does not work

Tags: soql, custom-object, standard-objects, child-to-parent

Good morning,

In the custom object `Equipment_maintenance_item__c` there is a `lastModifiedById` lookup field to the `User` object.

My understanding is that `User` is the parent object, and that to query it from the child my query should be like this:

`Select createdbyId, User__r.id from Equipment_maintenance_item__c`

However this does not work, and I cannot see why since the following query between two custom objects does work:

`Select createdbyId, Equipment__r.id from Equipment_maintenance_item__c`

I have been checking the documentation and other questions on the stack exchange but I cannot see what I'm missing, could anybody give me a hand?

Many thanks!

Comment: Select createdbyId, createdby.id from Equipment_maintenance_item__c

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I had no idea the Lookup field name replaces the name of the object!

Comment: @kurunve pls create an answer for this, otherwise the question stays open forever (or someone else might post an answer and you won't get the credits ;-)  )

Comment: I don't fully understand by we have to remove the 'id' bit in the field name and use the dot notation to access the fields, could anybody point me to a resource on this? I haven't seen anything like this in any of the books I have, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOQL does not refer to the Object API directly.
If you have a Look of User object with named `Created_By__c` then you have to use the given field API name only in your SOQL query.

```
SELECT Id, Created_By__c, Created_By__r.Name,.. FROM Equipment_maintenance_item__c
```

Same goes for standard fields as well.

```
SELECT Id, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name FROM Equipment_maintenance_item__c
```

to get the Name or any other Field.

For any Standard fields, you don't append `__r` to get related fields. But if you have any Custom Fields (even if referring to Standard Object you must use `__r` and actual field name. (Example 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, much clearer now!